# Add ip in config file mongodb

Tags: mongodb, configuration

I have install mongodb 3.6 on windows server 2012 and modify the config file for add new ip,

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db
security:
    authorization: enabled
net:
    port: 27017 
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.11
```

when i try to start the service, this send me the next message

```
The MongoDB service is starting.
The MongoDB service could not be started.

Service specific error: 48.

You can get more help with the NET HELPMSG 3547 command.
```

i check the log file and discover this message

```
2018-01-24T09:18:23.511-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "C:\data\mongod.cfg", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1,192.168.1.11", port: 27017 }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, service: true, storage: { dbPath: "c:\data\db" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "c:\data\log\mongod.log" } }
2018-01-24T09:18:23.512-0500 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: The requested address is not valid in this context.
2018-01-24T09:18:23.512-0500 I CONTROL  [serviceStopWorker] now exiting
```

now I modify the configuration file to add a space between the ips

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db
security:
    authorization: enabled
net:
    port: 27017 
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.11
```

and I start the service

```
The MongoDB service is starting ..
The MongoDB service started successfully.
```

again I check the log file and find the following

```
2018-01-24T09:24:53.807-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "C:\data\mongod.cfg", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.11", port: 27017 }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, service: true, storage: { dbPath: "c:\data\db" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "c:\data\log\mongod.log" } }
2018-01-24T09:24:53.808-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] getaddrinfo(" 192.168.1.11") failed: Unknown host.
2018-01-24T09:24:53.808-0500 W NETWORK  [initandlisten] Found no addresses for  192.168.1.11
2018-01-24T09:24:53.808-0500 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in c:\data\db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-01-24T09:24:53.808-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7679M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-01-24T09:24:54.029-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1516803894:28660][640:140720456536192], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 20/11264
2018-01-24T09:24:54.197-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1516803894:196669][640:140720456536192], txn-recover: Recovering log 20 through 21
2018-01-24T09:24:54.297-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1516803894:296682][640:140720456536192], txn-recover: Recovering log 21 through 21
2018-01-24T09:24:55.031-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-01-24T09:24:55.031-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: The file system cache of this machine is configured to be greater than 40% of the total memory. This can lead to increased memory pressure and poor performance.
2018-01-24T09:24:55.031-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/wt-windows-system-file-cache
2018-01-24T09:24:55.031-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-01-24T09:24:55.231-0500 W FTDC     [initandlisten] Failed to initialize Performance Counters for FTDC: WindowsPdhError: PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with 'The specified object was not found on the computer.' for counter '\Memory\Available Bytes'
2018-01-24T09:24:55.231-0500 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'c:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2018-01-24T09:24:55.232-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2018-01-24T09:24:55.232-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Service running
```

I have tried in many ways, with [] {}:; and always throws error, but when I leave the bindIp with 0.0.0.0 it lets me connect from other ips. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bindIp` is not a client IP but a server IP that represents the interface that mongodb is listening on. `0.0.0.0` is a special case that tells mongodb to listen on all available interfaces.

If you want to restrict access to mongodb from specific **client's** IP addresses, you can do it on [user or role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/index.html#setAuthenticationRestriction) level. In this case the server will still listen on all allowed interfaces, but will not allow users from unknown IPs to login.

This feature is enabled by `--auth` command line option when you start mongod, or in [config file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization).

**Please read** a [step-by-step guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/index.html) how to enable authentication properly.

An example of [createUser](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createUser/) command that allows `testUser` to connect from `192.168.1.11` IP only:

```
db.createUser({ user: "testUser",
                pwd: "testPassword",
                roles: [ { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ],
                authenticationRestrictions: [ { clientSource: ["192.168.1.11"] } ]
              });
```

The `clientSource` array can have a list of exact IPs or/and network masks in CIDR notation,  e.g. `192.168.1.0/24` will allow the user to connect from any IP from `192.168.1.0` to `192.168.1.255`.

Comment: Hello, I follow the instructions and I add the user to the database, but I try to connect by robo3t and he throws the following message  "Network is unreachable"

Comment: Is it reachable when you start mongod without `--auth` option?

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life